# Add class to container if it has two children

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to add the class `.events-row-fill` to `.events-row` if it has two children, but it's not working.

This is my script:

```
if($('.events-row').children().length === 2) {
  $('.events-row').addClass('events-row-fill');
}
```

HTML structure (minus content):

```
<div class="events-row">
  <div class="card"></div>
  <div class="card"></div>
  <div class="card"></div>
</div>
<div class="events-row">
  <div class="card"></div>
  <div class="card"></div>
</div>
```

Demo: [CodePen](http://codepen.io/ourcore/pen/JWXJjg)

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$(".events-row")` will return you an array of 2 jQuery elements (one for each of the `.events-row` you have in the DOM). You need to iterate over that array and check each one and apply classes accordingly.

```js
$(".events-row").each(function() {
  // .toggleClass("classname", true/false)
  $(this).toggleClass("events-row-fill", $(this).children().length === 2);
});
```

```css
.events-row-fill {
  background: yellow;
}
.events-row {
  border: 2px solid black;
  margin: 5px 0;
  padding: 5px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="events-row">
  <div class="card">1</div>
  <div class="card">2</div>
  <div class="card">3</div>
</div>
<div class="events-row">
  <div class="card">1</div>
  <div class="card">2</div>
</div>
```

Comment: I see. Thank you! Is `$(this).children().length === 2` the "state" and essentially a condition for `.toggleClass` to check?

Comment: Yeah, toggleClass (if provided 2 arguments), will **add the class if the second parameter is true**, and it will **remove the class if the second parameter is false**.